# crystal reports retrieve a value based on another value in same table

Tags: crystal-reports

New to Crystal, using SAP Crystal Reports 2013, I am needing to return as part of my detail section a record based on a record value in a different field in the same table.

I have a table, SAMPLE:

```
SAMPLE_NUMBER   TEXT_ID       ORIGINAL_SAMPLE   TEST
1               ParentID27    1                 F
2               ChildID27_1   1                 F
3               ChildID27_2   1                 T
4               ChildID27_3   1                 F
```

SAMPLE_NUMBER 2,3 and 4 are all related to SAMPLE_NUMBER 1, this link is maintained in the ORIGINAL_SAMPLE field.

In my crystal report I am needing to return return all records where TEST = T with the following information.

```
SAMPLE_NUMBER   PARENT_TEXT_ID     TEXT_ID      
 3              ParentID27         ChildID27_2
```

In SQL I would just join the table to itself as below.

```
SELECT  S.SAMPLE_NUMBER, Z.TEXT_ID AS PARENT_TEXT_ID, S.TEXT_ID
FROM SAMPLE Z JOIN SAMPLE S ON Z.SAMPLE_NUMBER = S.ORIGINAL_SAMPLE
WHERE S.TEST = 'T'
```

How do I achieve the same result in my report formula field?

Comment: Thanks Lan, I will keep that in mind going forward.

Answer (score 0):

Add the same table a second time to the report (it would be added as an alias that you can change) and join.

Join using the same logic as in your SQL. 
Filter (Record Selection Formula) using the same logic : as in your SQL
No need for a formula. Simply drag the desired columns into the detail section.

Comment: I have added it, but I am unsure of how to construct the formula to pull the required field from within Crystal.

Comment: Did you add the table to the database in Database Expert and give it an alias, or did you add the field to the report a second time from the table in your database?  The answer here is telling you to add the table to the database with an alias.  Then you link it properly and reference the field through the alias table.

Comment: Thanks MilletSoftware and R. McMillan, got it as directed. I was way over thinking something simple.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a Command and write your SQL directly. Database expert is a very limited tool and will restrict you in the future if you have to make changes in the SQL. Also Data expert can generate a single SQL statement, while in the command you can create a script and process the data in multiple statements (if supported by the database) .